# Pronoun in a topic

Tags: pronouns

What pronoun sounds good in a topic, subject pronoun or object pronoun?

A. 'Our society and we'

or

B. 'Our society and us'

Which is right?

I think B is right because an object pronoun doesn't need a verb after this. Like if we say:

'I like him.' it is ok, but we can't say:

I like he.

Comment: If you mean 'as the title for a topic', B is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

As a topic or subject title or isolated phrase, it can be either "We and our society" (more formal) or "Our society and us" (less formal).

Traditional grammar called for the subject pronoun to be used in many situations where we instinctively use the object pronoun.  The subject pronoun was seen as the default, while the object pronoun was seen as the marked or inflected form to be used where the pronoun was the object of a transitive verb or preposition (and not where it was the complement of "be").  The traditional grammatical prescription is still followed in formal style.  For example:

> It is I (*formal*) / It's me (*less formal*)

> Who wants an ice cream?  I do! (*more formal*) (but even in very formal usage we would never say "I" on its own here) / Who wants an ice cream?  Me! (*less formal*)

> "Withnail and I" (title of a British film released in 1987)

In the case of the subject forms, there are some very strong conventions about word order.  Where you have a coordinated phrase that uses "I", such as "Society and I" or "James and I", "I" must always come last (after "and") - whereas other pronouns (including "we") almost always come first (you cannot say "Our society and we" as an isolated phrase, and it sounds forced at the start of a sentence too).  Where an object form is used in a coordinated phrase, word order is more variable.